# Understand Google Play Developer Console's Crash Logs with Titanium

Tags: android, crash, appcelerator, crash-reports, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app published on Google Play. I have a few crashes. Below is one of the logs.

By looking at it, I have no idea where to start to find the cause. I don't see crashes when I run the app on my devices or on the emulators.

Any advice? Anyone understands it?

Usually how are these crash logs useful to Titanium developers?

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/degasltezt/degaslte:4.4.2/KOT49H/T235YZTU1AOE1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '6'
pid: 14192, tid: 14192, name: forerunner.frcc  >>> cc.forerunner.frcc <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    r0 00000000  r1 00003770  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 00000006  r5 00000002  r6 00003770  r7 0000010c
    r8 be8bf388  r9 416f4d4c  sl 418f92f8  fp be8bf39c
    ip 7a7bddf8  sp be8bf0b8  lr 4003f0dd  pc 4004e2d0  cpsr 000f0010
    d0  74726f6261204d56  d1  726174536576696e
    d2  2e736f2e6c616e75  d3  6e4965746f67796c
    d4  42017a2041fe02f0  d5  4206aab84213bc18
    d6  4243cbe84214db28  d7  42198dd0426a5e78
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000042e40000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000000004000  d17 0000000000000004
    d18 bfc9999a4fd4378f  d19 3fd55555ca7b73a4
    d20 2000000000000000  d21 0004000000000000
    d22 3fb10d6744103c71  d23 3f4ca2e96cce06d9
    d24 3ea9a055e07cebeb  d25 3fa97b4b8f4d3533
    d26 3f90ad3ae322da11  d27 bfadde2e4287ca34
    d28 3fb745ce9fcab7ba  d29 bfa2b4442c6a6c2f
    d30 bfb3b0f36ece7405  d31 3fc249252719ab54
    scr 20000013

backtrace:
    #00  pc 000222d0  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01  pc 000130d9  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
    #02  pc 000132ed  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03  pc 00012021  /system/lib/libc.so
    #04  pc 00021b84  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05  pc 00046b57  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmAbort+78)
    #06  pc 0004a2f9  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #07  pc 0004b7d1  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #08  pc 00070e23  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #09  pc 00070e41  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #10  pc 0001eacc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
    #11  pc 0004efab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
    #12  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

code around pc:
    4004e2b0 e8bd00f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
    4004e2c0 ea006e7e e92d50f0 e3a07f43 ef000000  
    4004e2d0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
    4004e2e0 ea006e76 e92d50f0 e3a070ee ef000000  
    4004e2f0 e8bd50f0 e3700a01 912fff1e e2600000  
    4004e300 ea006e6e e1520003 8a00008c f5d1f040  
    4004e310 e92d4001 e3520010 3a000024 e2603000  
    4004e320 e213300f 0a00000e e0422003 e1b0cf83  
    4004e330 44d1e001 44c0e001 24d1c001 24d1e001  
    4004e340 24c0c001 24c0e001 e1b0ce83 aa000001  
    4004e350 f4a1030d f480031d 3a000001 f421070d  
    4004e360 f400071d e2522040 3a000006 f421020d  
    4004e370 f421420d f5d1f100 e2522040 f400022d  
    4004e380 f400422d 2afffff8 e2922020 3a000002  
    4004e390 f421020d e2422020 f400022d e2822020  
    4004e3a0 e3120010 0a000001 f4210a0d f4000a2d  

code around lr:
    4003f0bc 447b4b13 42b3e010 4812d10e 44786a1e  
    4003f0cc ec94f7fb ea40f00d 46224631 e8f4f00f  
    4003f0dc d00a3001 e00b2400 2b00681b 480ad1eb  
    4003f0ec 44782403 ec82f7fb f001e002 6804fa87  
    4003f0fc fa84f001 46206005 bf00bd70 0003b2e6  
    4003f10c 0003b2da 0003b2d2 0003b2ae bf7ef7ff  
    4003f11c 43f0e92d 4a3d4b3c 589c447b 6823b08b  
    4003f12c 460d4606 f0019309 46a1fa69 8000f8d0  
    4003f13c d0482d00 f00f4628 280fffc5 d8444604  
    4003f14c ffe4f7ff d1064286 4629200f e90af00d  
    4003f15c d03c2800 482ee02e f7fb4478 482debc6  
    4003f16c e0154478 d11342b0 482b6a06 f7fb4478  
    4003f17c 4a2aec3e 447a2120 a8014633 fb32f013  
    4003f18c a8012101 fe34f01a 46061c42 e011d104  
    4003f19c 28006800 e02cd1e6 46294630 f00d4622  
    4003f1ac 1c43e946 d11e4607 fa28f001 29046801
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Android log analyzer or crash analytics tool will get you down to the Titanium JAVA code. Appcelerator crash analytics will often get you further, down to the JS method called:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Managing_Performance_and_Crash_Data