# Android Crash Report Diagnostic

Tags: android, crash, report, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Built an app using Appcelerator and seem to be getting this crash report a lot.
It can happen from anywhere from 10 seconds to 5 minutes and i cant seem to see a pattern which makes me think it may be a memory issue.

could someone please help point me in the right direction of what to do / even look for?

Many thanks in advance.

```html
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'lge/awifi_open_eu/awifi:4.4.2/KOT49I.V50020f/.1442277816:user/release-keys'
Revision: '11'
pid: 17156, tid: 17160, name: GC  >>> com.adzmedia.cureit <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 85443c34
    r0 42a24343  r1 85443c30  r2 42a24340  r3 42a1f8f8
    r4 5ba1dad4  r5 420b7008  r6 5ba1dc18  r7 42a242e8
    r8 00000000  r9 42a1f950  sl 416d4adc  fp 80000000
    ip 00000003  sp 5ba1da20  lr 4174c5f5  pc 4174c5e2  cpsr 900f0030
    d0  0000000000000000  d1  0000000000000000
    d2  0000000000000000  d3  0000000000000000
    d4  0000000000000000  d5  0000000000000000
    d6  0000000000000000  d7  0000000000000000
    d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    d16 0000000000000000  d17 0000000000000000
    d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
    d20 0000000000000000  d21 0000000000000000
    d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
    d26 0000000000000000  d27 0000000000000000
    d28 0100010001000100  d29 0100010001000100
    d30 0000000000000000  d31 0000000000000000
    scr 20000010

backtrace:
    #00  pc 000755e2  /system/lib/libdvm.so (mspace_bulk_free+89)
    #01  pc 000764df  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapSourceFreeList(unsigned int, void**)+70)
    #02  pc 0003a0ac  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #03  pc 0002bd40  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapBitmapSweepWalk(HeapBitmap const*, HeapBitmap const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, void (*)(unsigned int, void**, void*), void*)+176)
    #04  pc 0003ae4c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmHeapSweepUnmarkedObjects(bool, bool, unsigned int*, unsigned int*)+284)
    #05  pc 0002c268  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCollectGarbageInternal(GcSpec const*)+452)
    #06  pc 000759cd  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #07  pc 00057b75  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    #08  pc 0000d2e8  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    #09  pc 0000d480  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
    4174c5c0 454f0908 f8dcd113 f0007004 f0400001  
    4174c5d0 f0270c02 18ba0707 ea4c1889 f8430002  
    4174c5e0 684a0c04 0001f042 60236048 4628e002  
    4174c5f0 fbf6f7fd d1d042b4 69eb68e9 d9134299  
    4174c600 21004628 ff24f7fd 42b4e00e 0207f020  
    4174c610 0c02eb01 e7ead1d2 22004805 44784905  
    4174c620 f7fd4479 e7e7fbc7 e8bd2000 bf0083f8  
    4174c630 0003bbd9 000441e8 43f8e92d 69874688  
    4174c640 2f004691 f500d038 682a75e0 0308f102  
    4174c650 0007f013 425cd002 0007f004 e0171814  
    4174c660 f1041f02 e0060008 bf9428f8 0010f104  
    4174c670 0020f104 42b02200 4631d202 47c0464b  
    4174c680 d10442bc 2d0068ad e8bdd1df 463483f8  
    4174c690 428c6829 686ad3f6 0c02eb01 d2f14564  
    4174c6a0 2b076863 f003d0ee f0230103 29010007  
    4174c6b0 0600eb04 e7d7d1d4 83f8e8bd bec8f7fd  

code around lr:
    4174c5d4 18ba0707 ea4c1889 f8430002 684a0c04  
    4174c5e4 0001f042 60236048 4628e002 fbf6f7fd  
    4174c5f4 d1d042b4 69eb68e9 d9134299 21004628  
    4174c604 ff24f7fd 42b4e00e 0207f020 0c02eb01  
    4174c614 e7ead1d2 22004805 44784905 f7fd4479  
    4174c624 e7e7fbc7 e8bd2000 bf0083f8 0003bbd9  
    4174c634 000441e8 43f8e92d 69874688 2f004691  
    4174c644 f500d038 682a75e0 0308f102 0007f013  
    4174c654 425cd002 0007f004 e0171814 f1041f02  
    4174c664 e0060008 bf9428f8 0010f104 0020f104  
    4174c674 42b02200 4631d202 47c0464b d10442bc  
    4174c684 2d0068ad e8bdd1df 463483f8 428c6829  
    4174c694 686ad3f6 0c02eb01 d2f14564 2b076863  
    4174c6a4 f003d0ee f0230103 29010007 0600eb04  
    4174c6b4 e7d7d1d4 83f8e8bd bec8f7fd e92d4b2d  
    4174c6c4 447b41f0 f8df4605 681880b0 b90844f8
```

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35616629/understand-google-play-developer-consoles-crash-logs-with-titanium

Comment: Seems this is a Enterprise only feature and i am on the plan before it :(

Answer (score 0):

A `SIGSEV` exception is a Segmentation Fault. You try to access something that has never been there or more likely garbage collected. This is hard to debug. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked) explains how you can trace this back to the exact Titanium SDK method, but then still the question is what JavaScript code if you use the same Titanium API on multiple occasions. It might be easier to see what you do (or automatically have done) right before it crashes and comment out pieces of code to see what causes it. Unfortunately since you say it happens at random times that still might be a challenge.